# Unable to extend my table in Overleaf

Tags: tables, page-breaking

[image]

I am writing my research paper and I have a comparison table and it does not extend to next page.
Here is the code, I am also very new to using overleaf tabular columns. Please let me know what is wrong with it. I have also attached an image for reference. Where you can see the table is not extended to next page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \caption{Related works Comparison table}
  \label{my-label}
{\small %
    \begin{tabular}{p{.18\textwidth}p{.22\textwidth}p{.2\textwidth}p{.2\textwidth}p{.2\textwidth}}
\hline 
\thead Title & Goal & Idea & Event \&\ Others & Technique and \&\ Model \\
\hline 
Soccer Event Detection  & Automatic systems for detection event in video &  Detect Object from single video frame with a confidence scores and followed by event detection. Instead of resampling pixels and features and classify those proposals, which is computationally expensive. A method is used to combine the region proposal and classification into one. & Ball possession event and kicking the ball. &    Event detection and Object Detection. \\

\hline
A Discriminative CNN Video Representation for Event Detection & The idea is to effectively leverage deep Convolutional Neural Networks to advance event detection, where only frame level static descriptors can be extracted by the existing CNN toolkits. & Performance can be significantly improved by taking advantage of an appropriate encoding method. Second, we propose using a set of latent concept descriptors as the frame descriptor, which enriches visual information while keeping it computationally affordable. &   Event detection & VLAD Encoding, Fisher Vector encoding, CNN Latent Concept descriptors. \\
\hline

    \end{tabular}%
}%
\end{table}
\end{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: A table environment can not break across pages. You need longtable for this. However, please also be aware that longtable can only insert page breaks between table rows, not within.

Comment: Since the text in your table cells are quite large, you might want to consider rotating the table to a landscape oriented page in order to adapt the column widths and reduce the amount of unnecessary white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following redesign based on `xltabular` to make sure the table is as wide as the available space and to allow mid table page breaks. Additionally, I used `pdflscape` in order to rotate the page to a landscape orientation and changed the column widths in order to minimize the amount of unnecessary white space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.2\textwidth}
                              p{.35\textwidth}
                              X
                              >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.15\textwidth}
                              >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.175\textwidth}}
\caption{Related works Comparison table}
\label{my-label}\\
\toprule 
Title & Goal & Idea & Event \&\ Others & Technique \&\ Model \\
\midrule 
\endfirsthead
\caption{Related works Comparison table - continued from previous page}\\
\toprule 
Title & Goal & Idea & Event \&\ Others & Technique \&\ Model \\
\midrule 
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Soccer Event Detection  & Automatic systems for detection event in video &  Detect Object from single video frame with a confidence scores and followed by event detection. Instead of resampling pixels and features and classify those proposals, which is computationally expensive. A method is used to combine the region proposal and classification into one. & Ball possession event and kicking the ball. &    Event detection and Object Detection. \\

\midrule
A Discriminative CNN Video Representation for Event Detection & The idea is to effectively leverage deep Convolutional Neural Networks to advance event detection, where only frame level static descriptors can be extracted by the existing CNN toolkits. & Performance can be significantly improved by taking advantage of an appropriate encoding method. Second, we propose using a set of latent concept descriptors as the frame descriptor, which enriches visual information while keeping it computationally affordable. &   Event detection & VLAD Encoding, Fisher Vector encoding, CNN Latent Concept descriptors. \\

\end{xltabular}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot